# How to save a PDF document without having to choose the file name each time?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I'm reading academic papers in PDF format in Adobe Acrobat Reader. However, when I highlight text and save the document, Acrobat keeps asking me to re-choose the file, rather than just overwriting the existing document.

It takes a lot of time every time I save, especially when I am using many papers. Is there a way to just have Adobe Reader automatically overwrite the file? Or is there some other solution?

Comment: You did not specify which device and OS you are reading on. That is important. You might simply have weak HW or you may have configured the SAVE settings less than optimally.

Comment: Just use another program as @idiotprogrammer suggested

Answer (score 1):

I often read PDFs in a cloud-based ebook reader such as Google Play Books (GPB). You can view GPB on a PC or on any android or IOS device).

GPB annotates epub files easily and saves the edits to the cloud quickly. But I just checked on a PDF -- and GPB doesn't allow annotation on PDFs.

You can try another cloud-based reader like BlueFire reading app. On my android device I annotated a PDF on Bluefire and it does not give me this prompt.

The Adobe Digital Editions app is another option. On my android tablet it annotates PDFs easily without requiring that you save. (ADE) also has a desktop app.

Adobe Acrobat Reader is a heavy app; ADE is newer and more portable (although it is more geared towards reading epub ebooks than PDFs).